# How to enable Aarch32 instruction set on ARMv8-a?

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, intrinsics

[Raspberry Pi 3 uses a Broadcom SoC with and ARMv8 A53 core](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/raspberry-pi-3-specs-benchmarks/). It also uses a 32-bit OS based on Debian Jessie. According to ARM's [ARM NEON programming quick reference](https://community.arm.com/groups/android-community/blog/2015/03/27/arm-neon-programming-quick-reference#_ednref3), Section 3.2, *Instruction set*:

> The ARMv8-A AArch32 instruction set consists of A32 (ARM instruction set, a 32-bit fixed length instruction set) and T32 (Thumb instruction set, a 16-bit fixed length instruction set; Thumb2 instruction set, 16 or 32-bit length instruction set). It is a superset of the ARMv7-A instruction set, so that it retains the backwards compatibility necessary to run existing software. There are some additions to A32 and T32 to maintain alignment with the A64 instruction set, including NEON division, and the Cryptographic Extension instructions. NEON double precision floating point (IEEE compliance) is also supported.

I kind of asked a similar question a while back on the GCC mailing list at [How to test Aarch32 execution environment on Aarch64?](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2016-06/msg00097.html) But I did not quite understand the answer:

> Once you're compiling with an arm toolchain the CRC extension can be enabled through `-march=armv8-a+crc` or selecting an `-mcpu` option that enables it. To enable the Crypto extension you'll have to specify the right `-mfpu` option.

My question is simple... How do I enable both CRC and Crypto extensions for the Raspberry Pi 3?

---

Here are some attempts that don't work.

Attempt (4) is similar to how we do it natively under Aarch64: `gcc -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mtune=cortex-a53`. Attempt (5) actually enables CRC, but I can't seem to get anything else enabled, like `PMULL`, `PMULL2`, `AES`, `SHA1` and `SHA2`.

1. `gcc -D__ARM_FEATURE_CRYPTO -D__ARM_FEATURE_CRC -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon test.cc -o test.exe`
2. `gcc -D__ARM_FEATURE_CRYPTO -D__ARM_FEATURE_CRC -march=armv8-a+crc -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon test.cc -o test.exe`
3. `gcc -D__ARM_FEATURE_CRYPTO -D__ARM_FEATURE_CRC -march=armv8-a -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon test.cc -o test.exe`
4. `gcc -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon test.cc -o test.exe`
5. `gcc -march=armv8-a+crc -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon test.cc -o test.exe`
6. `gcc -march=armv8-a -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon test.cc -o test.exe`

---

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Raspbian 4.9.2-10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-armhf/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-armhf --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-armhf --with-arch-directory=arm --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply, "the right `-mfpu` option" should be [`-mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html#index-mfpu-1555).

Comment: Note that even for a Pi 2, you'd probably want `-mfpu=neon-vfpv4` - `-mfpu=neon` is for the older Cortex-A8/A9 FPUs and misses out on a few newer instructions.

Comment: Where do these guys come up with this stuff.... That one even escaped the [ARM blog on GCC command line switches](http://community.arm.com/groups/tools/blog/2013/04/15/arm-cortex-a-processors-and-gcc-command-lines). It sure would be nice if it was documented at [AArch64 Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html).

Comment: @jww: You're not targeting AArch64.  Relevant compiler options always depend on the target, not the host.  It doesn't matter that you're cross-compiling from an AArch64 system.  I'm sure there are x86 options that only apply with `-m32`, but not with `-m64` or `-mx32`, or vice versa.  Although I think the docs lump things together a lot more for x86, because the architectures are maybe more similar than AArch32 and AArch64.

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew I should have asked that question here a few days ago. A related question: do I also need `-mfloat-abi=hard`; or does the Aarch32 ABI already call it out? For completeness, here are the platform flags I have gathered so far for the device: `-march=armv8-a+crc -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8`.

Comment: @PeterCordes - How do we differentiate what applies to 32-bit ARMv7 and below, and ARMv8 with Aarch32? Its funny you bring up `m32` - that's another one that seems like a logical choice (to me) to control these flags. I.e., `-march=armv8-a+crc+crypto` is Aarch64; while `-march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -m32` is Aarch32.

Comment: @jww: Isn't AArch32 just another extension to 32-bit ARM, with a fancy name?  I mean it's not even a new mode of execution or instruction format like Thumb2, so it seems normal to me for documentation about it to be in the ARM section.  (which it does, with entries for things like `-mrestrict-it`.  Hmm, I'd forgotten AArch32 wasn't 100% backwards compatible with previous 32-bit ARM code).  It sucks when your idea of where the docs should have been doesn't match where they actually are, but I think gcc's organization makes sense.  It would be nice if the ARM section mentioned AArch32 by name...

Comment: @jww That compiler's configured for a hard-float target (`--with-float=hard`), so `-mfloat-abi=hard` should be the implicit default. As for compiler confusion, the AArch64/AArch32 difference is more comparable to IA-64/IA-32 than to AMD64, i.e. there are sufficient ISA differences that trying to cram both into the same GCC backend wasn't going to happen. Also, I'm not surprised that a blog which predates GCC having 32-bit ARMv8 support doesn't mention ARMv8 options ;)

Comment: Is it possible to use the ```umaddl``` instruction on an ARMv8 processor in Aarch32 state?