# Cross-compilation QT 5.15 on Raspberry pi3 with qtwebengine

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3, qtwebengine

I am trying to cross compile QT 5.15.2 for a Raspberry Pi 3. I am following this guide:
https://ebsolution31.wordpress.com/2020/10/08/cross-compile-qt/

I can cross compile qtbase, but I failed many times to cross compile qt-webengine.
After the make command of the qtwebengine every times I get this error:

```
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make[3]: *** [Makefile.gn_run:344: run_ninja] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/raspi/qt_source/qt_5.15.2/qtwebengine/src/core'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:82: sub-gn_run-pro-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/raspi/qt_source/qt_5.15.2/qtwebengine/src/core'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:79: sub-core-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/raspi/qt_source/qt_5.15.2/qtwebengine/src'
make: *** [Makefile:49: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
```

I saw in many forum that could be related to a RAM problems or a lack of resources. I have tried to give the command on a 16 GB RAM machine and also tried to create a big swapfile without any result.

Could you please help me to find a solution?

I will post my .config summary configuration of the qtbase and of the qtwebengine:

```
Configure summary QTBASE:

Building on: linux-g++ (x86_64, CPU features: mmx sse sse2)
Building for: devices/linux-rasp-pi3-vc4-g++ (arm, CPU features: neon)
Target compiler: gcc 7.4.1
Configuration: cross_compile compile_examples enable_new_dtags largefile neon shared shared rpath release c++11 c++14 c++17 c++1z concurrent dbus reduce_exports stl
Build options:
  Mode ................................... release
  Optimize release build for size ........ no
  Building shared libraries .............. yes
  Using C standard ....................... C11
  Using C++ standard ..................... C++17
  Using ccache ........................... no
  Using new DTAGS ........................ yes
  Relocatable ............................ yes
  Using precompiled headers .............. no
  Using LTCG ............................. no
  Target compiler supports:
    NEON ................................. yes
  Build parts ............................ libs
Qt modules and options:
  Qt Concurrent .......................... yes
  Qt D-Bus ............................... yes
  Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... yes
  Qt Gui ................................. yes
  Qt Network ............................. yes
  Qt Sql ................................. yes
  Qt Testlib ............................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............................. yes
  Qt Xml ................................. yes
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... yes
  udev ................................... yes
  Using system zlib ...................... yes
  Zstandard support ...................... no
Qt Core:
  DoubleConversion ....................... yes
    Using system DoubleConversion ........ yes
  GLib ................................... yes
  iconv .................................. no
  ICU .................................... yes
  Built-in copy of the MIME database ..... yes
  Tracing backend ........................ <none>
  Logging backends:
    journald ............................. no
    syslog ............................... no
    slog2 ................................ no
  PCRE2 .................................. yes
    Using system PCRE2 ................... no
Qt Network:
  getifaddrs() ........................... yes
  IPv6 ifname ............................ yes
  libproxy ............................... no
  Linux AF_NETLINK ....................... yes
  OpenSSL ................................ no
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
  OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ no
  DTLS ................................... no
  OCSP-stapling .......................... no
  SCTP ................................... no
  Use system proxies ..................... yes
  GSSAPI ................................. no
Qt Gui:
  Accessibility .......................... yes
  FreeType ............................... yes
    Using system FreeType ................ yes
  HarfBuzz ............................... yes
    Using system HarfBuzz ................ no
  Fontconfig ............................. yes
  Image formats:
    GIF .................................. yes
    ICO .................................. yes
    JPEG ................................. yes
      Using system libjpeg ............... yes
    PNG .................................. yes
      Using system libpng ................ yes
  Text formats:
    HtmlParser ........................... yes
    CssParser ............................ yes
    OdfWriter ............................ yes
    MarkdownReader ....................... yes
      Using system libmd4c ............... no
    MarkdownWriter ....................... yes
  EGL .................................... yes
  OpenVG ................................. no
  OpenGL:
    Desktop OpenGL ....................... no
    OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ yes
    OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ yes
    OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ yes
    OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ yes
  Vulkan ................................. no
  Session Management ..................... yes
Features used by QPA backends:
  evdev .................................. yes
  libinput ............................... yes
  INTEGRITY HID .......................... no
  mtdev .................................. yes
  tslib .................................. no
  xkbcommon .............................. yes
  X11 specific:
    XLib ................................. yes
    XCB Xlib ............................. yes
    EGL on X11 ........................... yes
    xkbcommon-x11 ........................ yes
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. yes
  EGLFS details:
    EGLFS OpenWFD ........................ no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 .......................... no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 Wayland .................. no
    EGLFS RCAR ........................... no
    EGLFS EGLDevice ...................... yes
    EGLFS GBM ............................ no
    EGLFS VSP2 ........................... no
    EGLFS Mali ........................... no
    EGLFS Raspberry Pi ................... no
    EGLFS X11 ............................ yes
  LinuxFB ................................ yes
  VNC .................................... yes
Qt Sql:
  SQL item models ........................ yes
Qt Widgets:
  GTK+ ................................... no
  Styles ................................. Fusion Windows
Qt PrintSupport:
  CUPS ................................... yes
Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... yes
  PostgreSQL ............................. yes
  SQLite2 ................................ yes
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... yes
Qt Testlib:
  Tester for item models ................. yes

Note: Also available for Linux: linux-clang linux-icc

Note: PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR automatically set to /home/administrator/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/home/administrator/raspi/sysroot/usr/share/pkgconfig:/home/administrator/raspi/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig

Note: PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR automatically set to /home/administrator/raspi/sysroot

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into '/home/administrator/raspi/qt5pi'.


Configure summary QTWEBENGINE:

Qt WebEngine Build Tools:
  Use System Ninja ....................... yes
  Use System Gn .......................... no
  Jumbo Build Merge Limit ................ 8
  Developer build ........................ no
  Sanitizer .............................. no
  QtWebEngine required system libraries:
    fontconfig ........................... yes
    dbus ................................. yes
    nss .................................. yes
    khr .................................. yes
    glibc ................................ yes
  Optional system libraries used:
    re2 .................................. no
    icu .................................. no
    libwebp, libwebpmux and libwebpdemux . no
    opus ................................. no
    ffmpeg ............................... no
    libvpx ............................... no
    snappy ............................... no
    glib ................................. yes
    zlib ................................. yes
    minizip .............................. no
    libevent ............................. no
    jsoncpp .............................. no
    protobuf ............................. no
    libxml2 and libxslt .................. yes
    lcms2 ................................ yes
    png .................................. yes
    JPEG ................................. yes
    harfbuzz ............................. no
    freetype ............................. yes
Qt WebEngineCore:
  Embedded build ......................... yes
  Full debug information ................. no
  Pepper Plugins ......................... no
  Printing and PDF ....................... no
  Proprietary Codecs ..................... yes
  Spellchecker ........................... yes
  Native Spellchecker .................... no
  WebRTC ................................. no
  PipeWire over GIO ...................... no
  Geolocation ............................ no
  WebChannel support ..................... no
  Kerberos Authentication ................ no
  Extensions ............................. no
  Node.js ................................ yes
  Support qpa-xcb ........................ no
  Building v8 snapshot supported ......... yes
  Use ALSA ............................... yes
  Use PulseAudio ......................... yes
Qt WebEngineQml:
  Support Qt WebEngine Qml ............... yes
  UI Delegates ........................... yes
  Test Support ........................... no
Qt WebEngineWidgets:
  Support Qt WebEngine Widgets ........... yes
Qt PDF:
  Support V8 ............................. no
  Support XFA ............................ no
  Support XFA-BMP ........................ no
  Support XFA-GIF ........................ no
  Support XFA-PNG ........................ no
  Support XFA-TIFF ....................... no
Qt PDF Widgets:
  Support Qt PDF Widgets ................. yes

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into '/home/administrator/raspi/qt5pi'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.
```

This is the a part of the build visible after make where there is a FAILED inside :

```
[4/13058] /home/administrator/raspi/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -MMD -MF obj/third_party/zlib/bundled_zlib/deflate.o.d -DUSE_UDEV -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_OZONE=1 -DOFFICIAL_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_QT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -DNO_UNWIND_TABLES -DCR_SYSROOT_HASH=3fcc1d4e44127006318371002a0f421a4fde2ab4 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -DZLIB_IMPLEMENTATION -DADLER32_SIMD_NEON -DINFLATE_CHUNK_SIMD_NEON -DCRC32_ARMV8_CRC32 -DARMV8_OS_LINUX -Igen -I../../3rdparty/chromium -I../../3rdparty/chromium/third_party/zlib -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fPIC -pipe -pthread -march=armv8-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon -mthumb -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-psabi -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-comments -Wno-packed-not-aligned -Wno-dangling-else -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu11 --sysroot=../../../../../../sysroot -c ../../3rdparty/chromium/third_party/zlib/deflate.c -o obj/third_party/zlib/bundled_zlib/deflate.o
FAILED: obj/third_party/zlib/bundled_zlib/deflate.o 
/home/administrator/raspi/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -MMD -MF obj/third_party/zlib/bundled_zlib/deflate.o.d -DUSE_UDEV -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_OZONE=1 -DOFFICIAL_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_QT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -DNO_UNWIND_TABLES -DCR_SYSROOT_HASH=3fcc1d4e44127006318371002a0f421a4fde2ab4 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -DZLIB_IMPLEMENTATION -DADLER32_SIMD_NEON -DINFLATE_CHUNK_SIMD_NEON -DCRC32_ARMV8_CRC32 -DARMV8_OS_LINUX -Igen -I../../3rdparty/chromium -I../../3rdparty/chromium/third_party/zlib -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fPIC -pipe -pthread -march=armv8-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon -mthumb -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-psabi -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-comments -Wno-packed-not-aligned -Wno-dangling-else -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu11 --sysroot=../../../../../../sysroot -c ../../3rdparty/chromium/third_party/zlib/deflate.c -o obj/third_party/zlib/bundled_zlib/deflate.o
In file included from ../../3rdparty/chromium/third_party/zlib/deflate.c:54:0:
../../3rdparty/chromium/third_party/zlib/contrib/optimizations/insert_string.h:58:42: error: attribute(target("arch=armv8-a+crc")) is unknown
                                          const Pos str) {
                                          ^~~~~
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-packed-not-aligned’
```

Comment: The error messages just tell us that `make` ran a command which failed. Please [edit] to include the lines above the current error message so that we can see which command exactly failed.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Based on the error message, seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631380/how-to-enable-aarch32-instruction-set-on-armv8-a

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way I didn't get how my problem is related to the question you linked me and what  I could do to solve the problem. :'(

Comment: I tried to give this command :
`make CFLAGS='-march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8'`
by the way I got the same error.